# Preserve newline in xml while using builder.parse method & Transformer

Tags: java, xml, javax.xml

The objective is to read from a xml file and write to a new xml file while preserving newlines. We need the Document object to perform other xml tasks.

Say source.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Code><![CDATA[code line1
code line 2
code line 3

code line 4]]></Code>
```

Now the destination should look the same with the newlines in the code element. But instead it ignores the newlines and makes it one line.

For writing, I am using the method below:

```
public static void writeFile(Document xml, File writeTo)
    {
        try
        {
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writeTo);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }
        catch(TransformerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't write file " + writeTo);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Document xml is obtained using Parse(File) method in DocumentBuilder. Roughly in the lines of:

```
File file; // a list of files is recursively obtained from a given folder.

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xml = builder.parse(file);
```

The builder.parse seems to be losing the newlines in the CDATA of Code element.

How do we preserve the newlines?
I am new to Java APIs.

Comment: How are fetching the `Document` object? Can you post the code that creates it and passes it to `writeFile`?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to read it as XML instead of as plain text?  If you don't need to treat it as XML, you should be able to do a direct read.

Comment: @manouti I updated the question with how Document object is obtained.

Comment: @BrianJ No particular reason, used it as that's what I found online. I am new to Java APIs.

Comment: @dushyantp I tried to reproduce the issue with the bare code and input XML but couldn't: I copied the XML as it looks in the question and it remained the same in the output, except for a removed small indentation before the element name. Is there an XSLT file being used? And why is the file merely being copied as it is? Maybe I'm missing something in the question.

Comment: Apologies, after having checked, it turns out I was asking the wrong question. The newlines in CDATA are lost because of the DocumentBuilder parse method. The write i.e. transform method is fine. I will modify the question and check if we can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When I put your snippets together I get this program:

```
public class TestNewLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xml = builder.parse(TestNewLine.class.getResourceAsStream("data.xml"));
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

and it prints out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Code><![CDATA[code line1
code line 2
code line 3

code line 4]]></Code>
```

As far as I understood, the newline is preserved already. What output did you expect?

Comment: Apologies, after having checked, it turns out I was asking the wrong question. The newlines in CDATA are lost because of the DocumentBuilder parse method. The write i.e. transform method is fine. I will modify the question and check if we can find a solution.